# Wordpress CSS not working properly

Tags: css

My theme css has gotten completely blanked all i'm seeing is plain background with unformatted text. I tried restoring to an older version of my db and also repairing my db but it didn't work. What seems to be the problem here? I've attached a picture for explaination[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't about the database at all. First of all be sure that it isn't any cache problem or something like that. Try with incognito mode or another browser and check if the issue persists.

If you still don't see any CSS applied, well most probably there isn't any CSS file loaded in the page.

Check the source code of the page and check if you can find the CSS file loaded, if yes check it's content. If there isn't then try to find in your theme files where the CSS file is supposed to be loaded. Searching for `wp_enqueue_style` in the whole folder should be enough (maybe also search for `wp_dequeue_style` to have some other clue).

If you cannot find any useful information, try to deactive all the plugins and check if the behavior persists.

Comment: didn't work! deactivated all my plugins resetted the .htaccess no luck :(

Comment: Did you even read what he is suggesting?

Comment: YES! Did everything. It didn't work!

Comment: What does it mean _It didn't work_? Is the CSS file loaded in the page? Has it a content? Isn't it loaded at all? Did you find in the theme code where it is enqueued?